# Is Visual Studio Not for Generic Web Design?

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, webmatrix

I have Visual Studio 2015 but noticed that I have the option to create applications in C#, F#, VB.NET, JavaScript, etc. but there doesn't appear to be options to create straight up HTML, CSS, JavaScript websites. Am I missing something?

I haven't used WebMatrix, but I know it supports a lot of web platforms but VS 2015 doesn't seem to...Is Microsoft pushing web development other than ASP.NET over to WebMatrix?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is primarily designed for web developers who use the ASP.NET framework. It has never really been intended for people who want to build straight up HTML, CSS and JavaScript web sites. Having said that, support for that kind of development is improving all the time. You can use the File » Open » Web Site option to target any folder on your machine you choose.

WebMatrix is no longer under active development. You can use it, but it is buggy and hasn't been updated for a number of years. [Expression Web](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36179) is free. Or you can use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which is also free, but is (at the time of posting) in Beta. VSCode appears to be the successor to WebMatrix.

Comment: We are talking about the same WebMatrix, right? I remember there was one way back in the day (early 2000's) with Matrix something name, and then there is this one: http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Comment: It seems that Microsoft is still developing tutorials for WebMatrix:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-use-webmatrix/
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/publishing

Comment: @davemackey The original Web Matrix (2003 - two words) was a free tool for developing ASP.NET 1.1 apps in C#. It was never updated to work with ASP.NET 2.0 and died a death. The more recent one (WebMatrix - one word) is a completely different product but appears to be suffering the same fate. The articles you referenced are not new. The Azure one was written in 2012, although it was updated a few months ago, it seems.The series on the ASP.NET site state they were written at the beginning of last year, but they are actually updates of a series written in 2011.

Comment: Strange and unfortunate, since WebMatrix offers a good starter environment and the Azure integration is sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Just do File, New Project. Then under Other Languages, expand TypeScript. Choose HTML Application with TypeScript. It will come with an `app.ts` file, but you can delete that and add any other client side tools you want.

Alternatively, use Visual Studio Code.